# print characters of a string or array in C Fast

Tags: c, arrays, printf, character

I'm coding a Game-Console and i save map of a game in character array and i need to print them colored (with different colors) in `CMD` so i write `print_map` function i attach it here , I used `printf` to print and `SetConsoleTextAttribute` to made them colored nut it was too slow printing.I need to print these characters of map fast so help me to print them colored and fast please.

````
void print_mapp(){
  clear();//clear screen
  int width,height,i,x,y;
  HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

  width = map_width;
  height = map_height;
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,background_color);

  x=4;
  y=2;

  for(i=0;i<width*(height+1);i++){
    SetPosition(x,y);// set cursor to (x,y)
    if(map[i] == ' '){
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,background_color);
        printf("%c",map[i]);
    }
    else if(map[i] == wall){
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,wall_color);
        printf("%c",map[i]);
    }
    else if(map[i] == solidblock){
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,solidblock_color);
        printf("%c",map[i]);

    }
    else if(map[i] == moveblock){
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,moveblock_color);
        printf("%c",map[i]);

    }
    else if(map[i] == deathblock){
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,death_blk_color);
        printf("%c",map[i]);

    }
    else if(map[i] == character){
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,character_color);
        printf("%c",map[i]);

    }
    else if(map[i] == rpoint){
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,rpoint_color);
        printf("%c",map[i]);

    }
    else if(map[i] == target){
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,target_color);
        printf("%c",map[i]);

    }
    else if(map[i] == object){
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,object_color);
        printf("%c",map[i]);

    }
    else if(map[i] == opp){
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,opp_color);
        printf("%c",map[i]);

    }

    else if(map[i] == bullet){
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,bullet_color);
        printf("%c",map[i]);

    }
    else if(map[i] == '\n'){
      SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,background_color);
      printf("%c",map[i]);
      x = 3;
      y++;
    }
    else{
      SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,wall_color);
      printf("%c",map[i]);

    }

    x++;
  }

}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that every call to `SetPosition()` and `SetConsoleTextAttribute()` causes `stdout` to be flushed. That results in a flush for every `char` you print.

So you should try to only call them when the position or character attribute differs from what you expect them to be.

Using fputc() rather than `printf("%c", ..)` may also give a theoretical speedup, but not enough that it matters in practice. But some, (including me) thinks the code looks cleaner that way...

So here is a suggested improvement:

```
void
set_attrib(HANDLE h, WORD attr, WORD *old_attr)
{
  if (attr != *old_attr)
    {
      SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, attr);
      *old_attr = attr;
    }
}

void print_mapp()
{
  clear();//clear screen
  int width,height,i,x,y;
  HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

  width = map_width;
  height = map_height;

  WORD old_attr;

  SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,background_color);
  old_attr = background_color;

  x=4;
  y=2;

  SetPosition(x,y);// set cursor to (x,y)


  for(i=0;i<width*(height+1);i++)
    {
      if(map[i] == ' '){
        set_attr(hConsole, background_color, &old_attr);
        fputc(map[i], stdout);
      }
      else if(map[i] == wall){
        set_attr(hConsole, wall_color, &old_attr);
        fputc(map[i], stdout);
      }
      ....  
      else if(map[i] == '\n'){
        set_attr(hConsole, background_color, &old_attr);
        fputc(map[i], stdout);
        x = 3;
        y++;
        SetPosition(x+1,y);// set cursor to (x,y)

      }
      else{
        set_attr(hConsole, wall_color, &old_attr);
        fputc(map[i], stdout);
      }

    x++;
  }

}
```

Other suggestions for speedup:

1. You could print ansi color code, rather than calling `SetConsoleTextAttribute()`
2. You could limit yourself to only print those lines that have changed after last call to `print_mmap()`

Some cleanup suggestions (won't have any significant effect on speed):

1. Move `fputc()` outside of `if` and `if else`
2. Rather have printable characters in `map[i]`, just have `enums` describing game-objects, and look up printable characters and attributes in a separate lookup-array.

Comment: thanks very much @HAL9000.I ll use your idea in my code.I hope it can help me